# SuiteSparse CHOLMOD throwing gpu_memorysize error despite passing all demo tests

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, nvidia, suitesparse

Ubuntu 16.04LTS; SuiteSparse 4.5.5; CUDA 8.0.61 (with performance upate); Nvidia driver 384.98;

I had GPU accelerated CHOLMOD successfully implemented into my code and working fine for several months. Then recently out of the blue (no changes to source code), I started seeing these errors in my output:

```
GPU failure in cholmod_gpu: gpu_memorysize 8.38861e+06 0 MB
CHOLMOD error: gpu memorysize failure
. file: ../GPU/cholmod_gpu.c line: 384
CHOLMOD error: CUBLAS initialization. file: ../GPU/cholmod_gpu.c line: 433
CHOLMOD error: cudaMemcpy(d_Ls). file: ../Supernodal/../GPU/t_cholmod_gpu.c line: 129
CHOLMOD error: CUDA stream. file: ../Supernodal/../GPU/t_cholmod_gpu.c line: 140
```

I suspected that a third party library had updated itself unattended. But my test of CHOLMOD/Demo/cholmod_l_demo (with export CHOLMOD_USE_GPU=1) proves that CHOLMOD itself is working perfectly fine and is employing the full GPU (monitoring activity with nvidia-smi). Similarly, the Cuda/samples are all working just fine. I've purged and reinstalled everything including Cuda, Nvidia drivers, and SuiteSparse. Ive tried various combinations of Cuda 8.0 and Cuda 9.0. To no avail, Cuda/samples and CHOLMOD/Demos still work perfectly fine but my CHOLMOD implementation throws the same error.

I've traced the issue to the cudaMemGetInfo() function. For some reason, it is reporting 0 available bytes on the GPU leading to the first error (gpu_memorysize)! The remaining errors seem to cascade off the first. This error is not happening in the CHOLMOD/Demo/cholmod_l_demo script, which suggests there is something wrong with my implementation. Yet, I have changed nothing in my implementation. Does anyone have any idea why cudaMemGetInfo() would report 0 available bytes? I think the answer to this question will help guide me to the solution.

I have looked up my unattended upgrade history and it appears I had some linux-headers and nvidia drivers updated around the time that I started seeing the errors. But I am not so sure the nvidia driver update is to blame since the CHOLMOD/Demo/cholmod_l_demo works perfectly fine. So I suspect it could be a linux-headers issue...

My implementation is spread across several files, so it might be worth looking at the [Github commit](https://github.com/yade/trunk/commit/bd1128a3bb24305b1e9a8ff33c7c8f3a4f6176cd#diff-d6259c170806f111743643999d415603). But as I mentioned, I have changed none of the source files in comparison to when CHOLMOD gpu acceleration was working for the past couple months.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I really appreciate the downvotes. I'm not sure I expected much more from stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason cudaMemGetInfo() was reporting 0 free bytes, was because my program did not have executable privileges on libcublas and libcudart. As soon as I run my program with "sudo" preceding it, the GPU is employed and CHOLMOD works as it did a few weeks ago.

I am unsure if the kernel changed the privileges, or if new privileges are required for certain .so installations. It is a bit of a mystery. But the solution is to use "sudo" to run the program.

Comment: Sorry, but this this answer doesn't make any sense. Executable files do not have privileges on other files. *Users* have privileges. If you can only run CUDA code as the root user, then your user ID no longer has the correct permissions on something (like the /dev entries created by the NVIDIA driver, or files which are part of the driver package).

Comment: I install cuda following the instructions presented by [nvidia](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html), so I am unsure why I would not have the correct permissions on those files.